# Django Postgres ArrayField makemigrations

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I'm looking to use the PostgreSQL-specific ArrayField in my Django project, but it doesn't show up in the migrations after I run makemigrations. Any ideas why?

Django v2.1
Postgresql v9.6.6

```
# Models.py
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import ArrayField

class MyClassName(models.Model):
    udi = ArrayField(models.CharField()),
    version = models.IntegerField()
```

Then I run: python3 manage.py makemigrations

```
# 0001_initial.py
migrations.CreateModel(
    name='MyClassName',
        fields=[
            ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
            ('version', models.IntegerField()),
        ],
    ),
```

As you can see, the field 'udi' is suspiciously missing.

Answer (score 2):

The problems are a comma at the end of the `ArrayField()` and `CharField` would need `max_length` too.

```
class MyClassName(models.Model):
    udi = ArrayField(models.CharField(max_length=10))
    version = models.IntegerField()
```

Run `makemigrations` again and you will get a migration you want.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! I can't believe the trailing comma was just failing silently and dropping the field! Nice catch!